# Blender slow response and lag?

Tags: performance

So this what happens, at first blender plays nice, no lag and fast response using the .zip installer. Then I decided to make a new partition for my 3D works and programs and this where it start to become laggish, I also tried to use trial version of C4D and MAYA and also it happens, same as laggish as blender. 
By the way, these are some of my specs:

**Processor:** Intel i3-4005U @ 1.70 GHz (4 CPUs)
**OS:** Windows10 Home SL 
**RAM:** 4096 MB 
**Renderer:**  nVidia Geforce 930M 

All drivers are updated, DirectX 12 Version

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/blender-is-currently-unusable-on-nvidia-gpus-m-mx-family?cb=1

Comment: are you saying that Maya, and Cinema 4D also lag? If that is the case, maybe this is not an issue with blender.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with the nVidia graphics cards and drivers - I had the same problem, and Tyler N supplied one answer.

Right click on your Blender shortcut, and select "Run with graphics processor > Integrated Graphics." If your computer tells you that "you don't have the privilege to select the graphics processor in this menu ", click "Open Nvidia Control Panel." Under "Program settings" click Add by "Select a program to customize." Add Blender, and then set it to integrated graphics in the box below.

Another alternative would be to download and install the Nvidia 375.95 driver version, which reportedly works okay with Blender.